# Hadoop & Hbase Installation and configuration Issues in a single node cluster on window

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I have recently started studying about NoSql and Big Data and decided to continue working on them. From couples of days I am trying to install and configure Hadoop and Hbase on my win2008 R2 64 bit machine. But unfortunately I have been unsuccessful, I am having different errors in each stage of installation. I am following below mentioned tutorials in this regards.

for Hadoop= http://blog.sqltrainer.com/2012/01/installing-and-configuring-apache.html 
for Hbase= http://ics.upjs.sk/~novotnyr/blog/334/setting-up-hbase-on-windows

First of all when I run jps command in /usr/local/hadoop directory, I don't see datanode there, these values are there only:

$ jps 
3984 NameNode
6864 Jps 
5972 JobTracker

However, when I navigate to this address 127.0.0.1:50070, its run fine. But when I try to run test wordcount example Job, It stuck for long at below mentioned position and I have to restart cygwin terminal:

11/06/13 13:43:01 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201005081732_0001
11/06/13 13:43:02 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%

Furthermore, I just Ignored it and moved to install and Configure Hbase on Top of Hadoop, Installation went well but now when I run different commands in hbase shell, I receive different errors, For Example if I run "list" command, I get ERROR: 
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Retried 7 times
If I run Scan 'test' command, I get ERROR: 
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find                                                                                                                 region for test,,99999999999999 after 7 tries.

I really don't know what to do, I have been searching for couple of days, but still could not find the exact solutions for my errors.

I really need help in this regard for you experts in order to successfully configured Hadoop and Hbase.

Here is My DataNode log:

```
2013-06-11 14:21:16,703 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving block blk_3811235227329042813_1246 src: /127.0.0.1:51511 dest: /127.0.0.1:50010
2013-06-11 14:21:16,721 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /127.0.0.1:51511, dest: /127.0.0.1:50010, bytes: 142452, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_1741700406, offset: 0, srvID: DS-2012389790-192.168.168.63-50010-1370448134624, blockid: blk_3811235227329042813_1246, duration: 8188439
2013-06-11 14:21:16,721 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder 0 for block blk_3811235227329042813_1246 terminating
2013-06-11 14:21:17,024 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving block blk_-7864325777801075696_1247 src: /127.0.0.1:51512 dest: /127.0.0.1:50010
2013-06-11 14:21:17,034 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /127.0.0.1:51512, dest: /127.0.0.1:50010, bytes: 368, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_1741700406, offset: 0, srvID: DS-2012389790-192.168.168.63-50010-1370448134624, blockid: blk_-7864325777801075696_1247, duration: 1775491
2013-06-11 14:21:17,035 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder 0 for block blk_-7864325777801075696_1247 terminating
2013-06-11 14:21:17,135 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving block blk_8363548489446884759_1248 src: /127.0.0.1:51513 dest: /127.0.0.1:50010
2013-06-11 14:21:17,145 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /127.0.0.1:51513, dest: /127.0.0.1:50010, bytes: 77, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_1741700406, offset: 0, srvID: DS-2012389790-192.168.168.63-50010-1370448134624, blockid: blk_8363548489446884759_1248, duration: 1461072
2013-06-11 14:21:17,146 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder 0 for block blk_8363548489446884759_1248 terminating
2013-06-11 14:21:17,481 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving block blk_2254833662532666780_1249 src: /127.0.0.1:51514 dest: /127.0.0.1:50010
2013-06-11 14:21:17,493 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /127.0.0.1:51514, dest: /127.0.0.1:50010, bytes: 20596, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_1741700406, offset: 0, srvID: DS-2012389790-192.168.168.63-50010-1370448134624, blockid: blk_2254833662532666780_1249, duration: 2206535
2013-06-11 14:21:17,494 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder 0 for block blk_2254833662532666780_1249 terminating
2013-06-11 14:21:17,861 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /127.0.0.1:50010, dest: /127.0.0.1:51516, bytes: 20760, op: HDFS_READ, cliID: DFSClient_-1869746926, offset: 0, srvID: DS-2012389790-192.168.168.63-50010-1370448134624, blockid: blk_2254833662532666780_1249, duration: 3906454
2013-06-11 14:21:18,234 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving block blk_-2949992568769351385_1250 src: /127.0.0.1:51518 dest: /127.0.0.1:50010
2013-06-11 14:21:18,244 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /127.0.0.1:51518, dest: /127.0.0.1:50010, bytes: 106, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_-163790033, offset: 0, srvID: DS-2012389790-192.168.168.63-50010-1370448134624, blockid: blk_-2949992568769351385_1250, duration: 1404625
2013-06-11 14:21:18,245 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder 0 for block blk_-2949992568769351385_1250 terminating
2013-06-11 14:21:18,290 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /127.0.0.1:50010, dest: /127.0.0.1:51519, bytes: 81, op: HDFS_READ, cliID: DFSClient_-1869746926, offset: 0, srvID: DS-2012389790-192.168.168.63-50010-1370448134624, blockid: blk_8363548489446884759_1248, duration: 694149
2013-06-11 14:22:00,557 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataBlockScanner: Verification succeeded for blk_3811235227329042813_1246

TaskTrakers Log:

2013-06-11 12:33:27,223 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting TaskTracker
STARTUP_MSG:   host = WIN-UHHLG0L1912/192.168.168.63
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.0.4
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.0 -r 1393290; compiled by 'hortonfo' on Wed Oct  3 05:13:58 UTC 2012
************************************************************/
2013-06-11 12:33:27,676 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2013-06-11 12:33:27,812 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2013-06-11 12:33:27,815 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2013-06-11 12:33:27,815 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: TaskTracker metrics system started
2013-06-11 12:33:28,402 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2013-06-11 12:33:28,411 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2013-06-11 12:33:28,697 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2013-06-11 12:33:28,852 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Added global filtersafety (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter)
2013-06-11 12:33:28,954 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLogsTruncater: Initializing logs' truncater with mapRetainSize=-1 and reduceRetainSize=-1
2013-06-11 12:33:28,963 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Starting tasktracker with owner as cyg_server
2013-06-11 12:33:28,965 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Good mapred local directories are: /tmp/hadoop-cyg_server/mapred/local
2013-06-11 12:33:28,982 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2013-06-11 12:33:28,984 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Can not start task tracker because java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-cyg_server\mapred\local\taskTracker to 0755
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkReturnValue(FileUtil.java:689)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.setPermission(FileUtil.java:670)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:509)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initialize(TaskTracker.java:723)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.<init>(TaskTracker.java:1459)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.main(TaskTracker.java:3742)

2013-06-11 12:33:28,986 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down TaskTracker at WIN-UHHLG0L1912/192.168.168.63
************************************************************/
```

In core-site.xml I have

```
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
 </property>
```

In Hdfs-site.xml I have

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>2</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>/home/hadoop/workspace/name_dir</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>/home/hadoop/workspace/data_dir</value>
  </property>
```

And In Mapred-site.xml I have

```
  <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:9001</value>
  </property>
```

Thanks in advance,

Regards

Salman

Comment: Showing us the logs will be helpful. Also, why do you want to do it on Windows?It's always messy.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. which log should I suppose to show, as there are 5 logs of Hadoop and 3 logs for Hbase? Well I never worked on other OS then windows, and fortunately Hadoop and Hbase could work on windows too. But I do agree that it seems messy to use hadoop and Hbase on windows.

Comment: OK...since multiple things seem to be frozen we'll start with hadoop daemons first and proceed further to hbase.show me the latest datanode  and tasktracker logs first.also your config files.

Comment: @Tariq, I have added said logs and config files in the question, please help me, I really out of my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Create a directory, say `/home/hadoop/workspace/temp_dir` and add the property `hadoop.tmp.dir` with this directory as its value into your `core-site.xml` file. Then change the permissions of `/home/hadoop/workspace/data_dir` and `/home/hadoop/workspace/temp_dir` to 755 and restart Hadoop.